# Complexity of subset-generation algorithm

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, algorithms, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms

I'm trying to calculate the computational complexity of an algorithm which generates the power set of a set of items.

The algorithm works using the [recursive formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Recursive_formula) of the binomial coefficient

$$\binom nk = \binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom{n-1}k$$

Any result of $$ \binom{n-1}k $$ is appended (so this is O(1)) but the results of $$ \binom{n-1}{k-1} $$ need to prepend an element of the set to each result (and this takes time proportional to the result).

As an example: the power set for the set 1,2,3 is as follows:

```
 for k from 0 to 3 (the set's size)
   calculateSubsets(set, k);

 calculateSubsets(set, k)
 {
   el = take the first item from the set (set is now one element less)
   append_result(calculateSubsets(set, k));
   other_result = calculateSubsets(set, k-1);
   for each item in other_result
     item = el + item // Prepend el to the item
   append_result(other_result)
 }
```

since appending it's done in constant time, I suppose the bulk of the work (proportional to the input) is the prepending of the set's item.

Can somebody help me out with calculating the bound for this recursion?

Comment: When you say you are computing the power set, are you actually generating a data structure in memory that is of size $2^n$, where $n$ is your original set size?

Comment: $\binom{i}{i} = 1$, so the sum is equal to $N + 1$. I think you've probably made a mistake in your analysis.

Comment: @PeterTaylor the prepending operation is probably the bulk of the work but I got it wrong with the previous writing. I'm editing the last part of the message. Let me know if this is somewhat clearer.

Comment: @ColmBhandal Yes, correct. I added the complete pseudocode for clarity's sake (and because the previous formula was wrong)

Comment: OK I'll take a look. Immediately though I think you might be asking something a bit different from "computational complexity"- is it recursion depth you want?

Comment: I'm thinking your computational complexity is going to have to be $2^n$, if you are creating $2^n$ elements.

Comment: Also, the algorithm looks a bit weird to me. I'm not convinced you can append the result for $(set, k)$- I can't see how this is already calculated? I would say the fastest/cleanest way to generate all subsets would be to just brute force through each of the $2^n$ combinations- because you have to generate this many elements no matter what algorithm you choose, right?

Comment: @ColmBhandal well the algorithm might call the function multiple times with the same input so I thought it could be 'memoized'. I'm kinda sure this algorithm is at least $2^n$ but since the naive version is $n \cdot 2^n$ that would still be a win

Comment: If you want deep copies of all your sets, you'll be forced to do $O(n2^n)$ operations I think. If you're OK with shallow copies e.g. pointers to the original set, then I think you can do it in $O(2^n)$ the simple way.

Comment: It's not very clear to me what most of the operations are, or what the purpose of `k` is (it seems to be unused). If what you want is a way to iterate through a powerset efficiently then you should look into Gray codes.

Comment: @PeterTaylor what is the complexity of a gray code approach for generating subsets?

Comment: At a high level, $2^n$. At a low level, it depends on implementation details. There are probably some questions about it on the sister site stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have an array of size $2^n$. At each position in the array we store a representation of a subset by:

1. A pointer to some element in the original set.
2. A pointer to a lower index in the array (which is the remaining set)

Each index in the array, written in binary, represents the subset in question. Then we can generate all subsets with complexity $2^n$ by stepping through the array, and at each point pointing to one element in the original set and one lower element in the array (representing the remaining set). Since this is $2$ operations per iteration, which is constant, we achieve the complexity $2^n$.

Comment: On reflection, I would have to advise against using this for any *practical* application. Because traversing through each subset's elements is no more efficient than simply creating the subset on the fly from a binary representation. In other words, what I'm saying is, there's no point in storing all the subsets (at least not that I can see). You can just represent subsets as binary numbers, where the index of each digit represents the element and the value $1/0$ represents in/out respectively.